# TTK Treeview only showing the first word when new lines are inserted into it

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

Simple piece of code that gets the name of a song and its artist from a SQL database, and it is put into the tree. I have checked and the output from c.execute contains artists with both their first and last name, however when I look at the tree view only the first name (or the first word) is showing up. I do not understand why this is happening. This only applies to the second column, as the first one is not affected.

```py
def songs(root):
        tree = ttk.Treeview(root,columns=['Song Name'])

        tree.heading("#0",text="Artist")
        tree.heading("Song Name",text="Song Name")

        DB = sqlite3.connect("DB.db")
        c = DB.cursor()
        DBSongs = c.execute("""SELECT * FROM Songs""").fetchall()
        songs = []



        for ID, songName, artist in DBSongs:
          songs.append([songName,artist])

        print(songs)
        for songName, artist in songs:
            tree.insert('','end',text=str(songName),values=(artist))
        tree.pack()
```

The output of songs is a list, [["You're beautiful", 'James Blunt'], ['Wisemen', 'James Blunt'], ['No Bravery', 'James Blunt']…

Comment: `values=(artist,)`. Note the trailing comma.

Comment: @HenryYik Thank you so much, I didn't realise that that was necessary.

Comment: From Python docs: _...A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1 items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses). Ugly, but effective._ More on this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).